# How to check contents of a folder using Python

Tags: python, directory, cpython

How can you check the contents of a file with python, and then copy a file from the same folder and move it to a new location?
I have Python 3.1 but i can just as easily port to 2.6
thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for example

```
import os,shutil
root="/home"
destination="/tmp"
directory = os.path.join(root,"mydir")
os.chdir(directory)
for file in os.listdir("."):
    flag=""
    #check contents of file ?
    for line in open(file):
       if "something" in line:
           flag="found"
    if flag=="found":
       try:
           # or use os.rename() on local
           shutil.move(file,destination)
       except Exception,e: print e
       else:
           print "success"
```

If you look at the [shutil doc](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html), under .move() it says

```
shutil.move(src, dst)¶

    Recursively move a file or directory to another location.
    If the destination is on the current filesystem, then simply use rename. 
Otherwise, copy src (with copy2()) to the dst and then remove src.
```

I guess you can use copy2() to move to another file system.

Comment: Don't give people code with `except Exception`, which is a bug. You do not provide a reasonable response to lots of exceptions that could be raised, such as `KeyboardInterrupt`.

Comment: In 2.5, Exception inherits from BaseException. do you think it will catch KeyboardInterrupt? OP has 3.1 and 2.6.

Answer (score 1):

[`os.listdir()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.listdir) and [`shutil.move()`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.move).

Comment: It can move files anywhere across the filesystem, including mounted network drives.